# Javascript key value array storing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am here today with a question to do with key value pair arrays.

my html is as follows

```
<input type="checkbox" class="data" id="task_checked" value="1" email="a@a.com">
<input type="checkbox" class="data" id="task_checked" value="2" email="b@b.com">
```

I would like to store the following data as an array like below:

```
"1" => "a@a.com"
"2" => "b@b.com"
```

My Javascript currently is as follows:

```
var newTasksArr = new Array();

$("#task_checked:checked").each(function() {
    var email = $(this).attr("email");
    var id = $(this).val();
    newTasksArr['id'] = email;

});
```

Perhaps I am using the Jquery .each() wrong, could someone shed some light in to my question please?

Thank you for you reading.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right, you just need to remove the quotes around `'id'` so that it uses the value the id variable contains, instead of the literal string `'id'`.

You should also use an object (`{}`) instead of an array (`[]`).

```
var newTasks = {};
$("#task_checked:checked").each(function() {
    var email = $(this).attr("email");
    var id = $(this).val();
    newTasks[id] = email;
});
```

Comment: @PeterOlson: note that the values of "id" will be sequential integers, though. Your suggested change to an object may have consequences that are unexpected to BaconJuice. Compare: `var a=[],b={}; a['0'] = 'x'; a['1'] = 'x'; b['0'] = 'x'; b['1'] = 'x'; alert(a.length); alert(b.length);`

Comment: @DavidHedlund He seemed to be fairly specifically asking for key-value storage, but it looks like he might be coming from PHP, which conflates arrays and key-value dictionaries even more than JavaScript does.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues :

In Javascript, an Array may only have sequential, numeric keys. If you want to use strings as keys, you want an Object.

If you want to insert an element with a key equal to the value of `id`, then you want `newTasksArr[id] = email;` without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid duplicating Ids in your markup.  The following should help, however you might want to tweek the jquery selector to include a context.

```
var arr = {};

$('input:checked').each(function() {
    var $t = $(this);

    var email = $t.attr("email");
    if (!email) {
        // you may wish to do something if email is missing
    }

    var id = $t.val();
    if (!id) {
        // deal with the error
    }

    arr[id] = email;
});
```